# Localhost refuses connection from Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, server

I am making a single web app that takes information from MYSQL database and displays it on screen using AngularJS and NodeJS. I have set up a node.js server that gives out JSON file from a database. It works fine if I connect to it like this: 192.168.1.57:8888 which is my home server ip or remote connecting my server and using localhost:8888. Doing this downloads the JSON file on my computer.

However. If I'm using javascript to get JSON file from the server it gives me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have tried connecting to the server with both AngularJS and JQuery and they both give the same error. I've also tried 127.0.0.1 and that doesn't work either. What can I do to fix it or can I do this with a better alternative way?

This is the server code in node.js

```
var http = require("http");
mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
user: "test",
password: "test",
database: "test"

});


http.createServer(function (request, response) { 

request.on('end', function () { 

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM feedback;', function (error, rows, fields) { 
        response.writeHead(200, { 
            'Content-Type': 'x-application/json' 
        }); 

        response.end(JSON.stringify(rows)); 
    }); 
}); 


}).listen(8888);
```

this is the client side in angularJS:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('question', [ ]);

app.controller("ServerController", [ '$http', function($http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:8888").success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("success");
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("error");
    });

} ]);
}
)();
```

Comment: "However. If I'm using javascript (which I'm running on Apache2 at my web server) " - Are you running the javascript from the same machine the apache2 server is on?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry. I got confused fixing the problem. Of course it runs on browser as you said :) I also included the code

Comment: @theatlasroom It is running in the browser. Sorry about confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a guess at it, you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which requires that the page making the ajax request be in the same origin as the resource it's requesting (or that the server serving the resource supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and allows the page's origin).

Two different ways this might be hitting you (I can't tell which, the question doesn't give enough information):

- **If** the browser code is running in a page loaded from the file system, not via HTTP, then it's a cross-origin request because the protocols don't match (`file:` vs. `http:`).
- If the page has not been loaded from `localhost:8888`, but instead from some other port on `localhost`, then the origins don't match because the port numbers are different.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure this is the reason. Now just finding out how to fix the problem. Thanks